# Spring : call REST API after receiving response from another REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, api

I have a controller that calls a webservice to **start a batch job**, when the result is returned, it should call another REST API based on this result. Then it should wait for the new result, and return this second result to user:

```
@RestController
public class LaunchController {
    @PostMapping(path = "/launch", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<LaunchResult> launch(@Valid @RequestBody LaunchParams params) {
    // in launch() I call the first REST API
    LaunchResult result = myService.launch(params);
    // here I need to call another REST API
    AnotherResult result2 = callAnotherWebAPIBasedOnThisResult(result);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(result2);
}
```

Now I want to know that is it good practice to do it like this (synchronously) and all in one controller ? Exist other way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller is perfectly fine as it does not have any application logic inside and it actually calls the service methods. But It lacks the exception handling. You have catch with proper exceptions with try catch block or throws keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The decision to convert the endpoint to an asychronous one depends on a few factors :

1. Is the batch job going to take time to be executed.
2. Can this process be converted to an asynchronous one.
3. Does the use case expect the user to wait until the action is completed.

If the your answer is yes, it's better to convert the endpoint to an ayschronous one and update the user with the details later after all processes including the batch processes are completed . It's always better NOT to keep the user waiting for a response. Non-blocking requests makes sense when you are dealing with a lot of data and processing needed for this data. Also, by making this request asynchronous you will have better control over the processing stages and provide the user with better statistics incase any of the processing stage resulted in failure. For instance the batch job could fail or the second rest api call could result in an error.